# How to connect to a server running as Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

The server runs on 9999

- and says "Hello world"
- code is here: https://github.com/fodon/step-two-jenkins.git
- all you've to do is run

  java -jar target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- see results here: http://localhost:9999

The PROBLEM starts when I try to access the page on a pipeline running on Jenkins.

I exposed port 9999 with this command:

```
docker run --rm  -u root \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 9999:9999 \
-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v "$HOME":/home  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

When I run the pipeline containing my-app

I can't see the message from the server on :

```
http://localhost:9999
```

... even though I can see jenkins at :

```
http://localhost:8080
```

What prevents me from seeing the "Hello World" message from my-app running Jenkins?

Can you show me by fixing the above code?